# Javascript documentation generators like RubyDoc.info or YARD?

Tags: javascript, documentation, yard

I really need a nice Javascript documentation generator for an upcoming Javascript library I'm working on. Obviously, I need documentation for my library in order for people to understand it. I'm having a lot of trouble finding a good library for documentation, I've looked at many different projects but they're not what I need.

Is there any nice documentation generators for Javascript that create a [Rubydoc.info](http://www.rubydoc.info) or YARD style documentation in Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/

Not exactly same as YARD style, but more natively for Javascript and less Javaish IMHO

Comment: Tasty! Just what I was looking for. :-D

Answer (score 0):

There is also https://github.com/lsegal/yard-js.

Appears to be very experimental still and depends on the [parsejs](https://github.com/wycats/parsejs) which is not available as a gem yet. But for JS projects that use some sort of class construct and do not mind the ruby dependency this direction might be worth pursuing.